# Create a bulleted bar graph in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I need to display a single value as a bulleted horizontal bar graph. It should look somehow like this:
[image]

There should be one bullet per value of 20. So to represent 100 I need 5 bullets. The bullets don't have to be interactive though they can be.

What is the best way to do it in highcharts?

So far I think about generating a number of fake points having Y the same and X changing in steps of 20. And then I make a usual line chart with markers having radius 10. This should work but looks too complex. Are there easier ways?

Thanks.

Comment: I did something similar for a stem/leaf plot, here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nfsxypsn/  | the 'binData' function does two things - it bins the data like a histogram, but it also creates the point data to display the scatter series in the manner you've described.  Look at how the 'pData' array is built, perhaps it will help

Comment: jlbriggs, thanks! I hoped for an easier way but your example will save me time.